# Can a random variable be viewed as a stochastic process where at any moment in time the distribution is independent of others and the same as others?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

- I.e. can the random variable be viewed as a more specific instance of
  a stochastic process -- a sort of constant stochastic process?
- I know that for analysis textbooks often look at a stochastic process
  as a collection of random variables at different moment in time (I
  think this makes analysis easier). But let's say the time steps
  becomes infinitely small and we have infinitely many distributions --
  to me it looks like a single random variable, whose domain is simply
  a function of time. So by that logic if at any moment in time the
  distribution is the same, then the domain is the same and it looks
  like a simple random variable where the domain is constant (not a
  function of time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, you certainly *can* view it that way, but I'm not sure what you get out of it.

To answer your second question (which may help with your first question), a random variable is usually *defined* as a mapping from a probability space to some measurable space of values.  If you make the domain a (non-constant) function of time, then it seems to me that makes it by definition *not* a single random variable.  A stochastic process adds the element of time, as well as introducing such properties as the *history* of the process, on which the current value can depend in any of a range of ways.

If it *is* a constant function of time, then I suppose you can treat it as samples of a single random variable.  It would help if I understood better what you think can be gained by looking at it this way.

Comment: I am trying to generalise (or almost make up a phylogenetic tree of stochastic processes). E.g. a Bernoulli Random Variable is an instance (a subclass if you will) of a Simple Random Walk, which itself is a subclass of a more generic General Stochastic Process. Perhaps it is my peculiar way of thinking, but I want to simplify or compress several concepts (random variables, stochastic processes) to a single construct (would be easier for notation and consistency). It is also easier for me to think that at any moment in time I am sampling from one thing (which may evolve through time).

Comment: In what way is a Bernoulli random variable an instance of a simple random walk?  Usually we understand Bernoulli random variables to be i.i.d., whereas the samples of a random walk usually aren't.

Comment: @ Brian Tung As I see it both Simple Random Walk (SRW) and the Bernoulli R.V. (BRW) share many similarities: both have the parameter $p$ that defines the codomain, both have a domain consisting of two elements. However the SRW has a richer domain $X(t)$ that is loosely speaking recursive on the previous sample value (perhaps other functions could be thought of). Whereas the domain for BRW is more restricted -- constant. In that way it feels like a subset of SRW.